# Kafka topic creation: Timed out waiting for a node assignment

Tags: scala, docker, apache-kafka

I've got a local Kafka running using the following `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:5.0.1"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: "confluentinc/cp-enterprise-kafka:5.0.1"
    ports:
      - '9092:9092'
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_METRIC_REPORTERS: io.confluent.metrics.reporter.ConfluentMetricsReporter
      KAFKA_GROUP_INITIAL_REBALANCE_DELAY_MS: 100
```

Trying to run a basic create topic using kafka-client 2.1.0 in Scala:

```
val props = new Properties()
props.setProperty(AdminClientConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092")

val adminClient: AdminClient = AdminClient.create(props)
val newTopic = new NewTopic("test", 1, 1.toShort)
val topicsF = adminClient.createTopics(List(newTopic).asJavaCollection)
val result = topicsF.all().get()
```

but after some time I get:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Timed out waiting for a node assignment.
```

I can create a topic using the command line:

```
kafka-topics --create \
    --zookeeper localhost:2181 \
    --replication-factor 1 \
    --partitions 1 \
    --topic test
Created topic "test".
```

[kafka AdminClient API Timed out waiting for node assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51325076/kafka-adminclient-api-timed-out-waiting-for-node-assignment) describes a similar problem using Java but the comment suggests that a system restart fixed the issue which is not the case on my side.

Comment: for future reference: for those looking at this question and wondering why the environment looks the same in the question and the answer - @Milan edited the question after the answer, see the question history

Answer (score 46, accepted):

If you're running Kafka in Docker (or similar) you need to configure the listeners correctly. [This article](https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/) describes it in detail.

[Here's an example](https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/community-components-only/docker-compose.yml#L22-L51) of a Docker Compose that you can use to access Kafka from your host machine.

*Disclaimer: I wrote the article :)*

Comment: I have updated my question with a docker-compose.yml file. With this setup, it still does not work.

Comment: where are you running your Scala code? on the Docker host or on another container?

Comment: I start the described docker-compose.yml and run the code locally from my MacOS as I just want to quickly develop without the need to build an sbt container and deploy it.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the Docker image you're using. I've updated my answer with some additional material

Comment: I have updated my question with the proposed docker-compose.yml. But when I run the simple code, it still fails with the same error.

Comment: Does it work if you use `kafkacat` as described in the article I link to?

Comment: This link is not working: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/cos/docker-compose.yml#L5-L28

Comment: @lloiacono fixed: https://github.com/confluentinc/demo-scene/blob/master/community-components-only/docker-compose.yml#L22-L51

Answer (score 15):

As @suh [pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53586130/kafka-topic-creation-timed-out-waiting-for-a-node-assignment#comment109584250_53587266).

An easier approach is uncomment kafka `server.properties` at line `:listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092` and it should work.

Comment: Hi sir, the above change worked for me but may I know the reason behind the need for change ?

Answer (score 7):

the main thing you have to do is

- first open your kafka server.properties from this path

  nano kafka-directory/config/server.properties
- now go to change this line. listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092 with this

  listeners=PLAINTEXT://your ip address:9092

your ip address must be an IP of the same network with the machine where you attempt to connect to kafka i mean if the ip of the client machine is late say 192.168.10.1 your listeners ip configuration must be as:

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.10.*:9092
```

- next modifie this configuration advertised.listeners= to this

  advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://your ip address:9092

thes two configurations must have the same IP and port at the end you got some thing like.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.10.10:9092
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.10.10:9092
```

Answer (score 2):

I think the `localhost` is the problem. In your `bootstrap-servers` properties use the advertised host (192.168.99.100) that you've defined in your compose file, instead of `localhost`, that should work.

Comment: Can you look inside the container, what's the advertised host defined in the server.properties? Then you can try doing a telnet to <host> 9092 from outside, and see if it's able to connect.

Comment: Inside of the container in server.properties: advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://192.168.99.100:9092.
> telnet 192.168.99.100:9092
192.168.99.100:9092: nodename nor servname provided, or not known

Comment: I have updated my question with a docker-compose.yml file. With this setup, it still does not work.

Comment: For me changing "listeners=PLAINTEXT://:9092" to "listeners=PLAINTEXT://localhost:9092" in the kafka server.properties worked. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

My advertised listeners were wrong and i did not have `KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP` configured.

A good example i found [here](https://github.com/tulios/kafkajs/blob/master/docker-compose.1_1.yml):

```
KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT,SSL:SSL,SSL_HOST:SSL,SASL_SSL:SASL_SSL,SASL_SSL_HOST:SASL_SSL
KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka1:29092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:9092,SSL://kafka1:29093,SSL_HOST://localhost:9093,SASL_SSL://kafka1:29094,SASL_SSL_HOST://localhost:9094
```

P.S: Use only what you need, for me it was `SASL_SSL` & `SASL_SSL_HOST`.

Answer (score 0):

Configuring using local Kafka.  un comment change and  the listeners PLAINTEXT to

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://127.0.0.1:9092
```

also, change the create topic command bootsrap-server to point to the plain text server address.

```
kafka-topics.bat --create  --bootstrap-server 127.0.0.1:9092 --replication-factor 1  --partitions 1 --topic TestTopic
```

Created topic TestTopic.

Answer (score 0):

for me I have changed the security in-bound rules,
my adding a new rule, allow traffic from anywhere and with IP-V4
it solved my problem. but consider your security issue use only my-ip address in security in-bound rules.